# Xcode 15.1 stuck for ever if breakpoints are enabled

Tags: xcode, debugging, breakpoints, xcode15

I am unable to debug my code because of these issues from Xcode 15.1. I made sure that I have enabled the debugging in my schema.

Please help me here as I see just a continuous spinner in my Xcode if i enable breakpoints.
[image]

I am also unable to see the view hierarchy and see the code coverage even though these settings have been enabled in my schema.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hid the "Variables View" beside the debugger. This helped me to increase the execution speed by a little bit.

[image]

Hope this will help others.